# He can swim better than I do/than I can

Tags: grammar

I came across the following multi-choice question in a bank of past exam questions of ENG1001 (taught as a compulsory subject in my university):

Randy is a very good swimmer, so he .......... swim better than I do.

A. can 
B. would 
C. may 
D. is going to

No answer key is given and almost all friends of mine prefer Option A. This raises two questions in my mind.

1. Is Randy's ability to swim better than I do the consequence of his being a very good swimmer? Rather, they are, I think, two facts simply coextensive with each other, and as such should be joined by 'and' instead of 'so'.
2. Is the sequence "can swim better than I can" more appropriate than "can swim better than I do"?

Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you missing some text before "every members"?

Comment: @Lawrence I've tried to edit it but the attempt is rejected. Hello, every member is the greeting I intended to write down.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. The lock-out might be a matter of timing - wait a bit and try again. Stack Exchange discourages the use of greetings in questions, by the way - they prefer that questions simply present the background and research done, together with a clear statement of an [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question that can be conclusively answered.

Comment: Tests sometimes incompletely encode the test-writer's frame of mind - answers other than the one intended might work, and sometimes leave out important context either because it is implied by the work done in class just before the test, or because the writer made unwarranted assumptions. // Questions related to learning the language are often referred to [ell.se], but I see that your question has to do with slightly broader issues.

Comment: @Lawrence I really appreciate your warm welcome. Could you please give me some opinion about the question? It's not clear enough to deal with. If so, please let me know and I'll try to rephrase it.

Comment: I'm working on an answer .... :)

Comment: @Lawrence Are you implying that there are more than one possible answer to this exam question?

Comment: The way I read your question, I thought you were simply using the test question as a springboard to your own. However, if we're discussing the test question itself, then yes - there's some justification for each of the multiple choice answers listed. (But answer "D" works better with "than I *would*" than with "than I *do*".)

Comment: I'm very sorry to get off the point. Actually, I thought the best answer to this question was Option C (may) because to me at first sight the proposition of the main clause was seemingly quite consistent with the probability that Randy may swim better than the speaker (in such a scenario where the speaker is a very good swimmer too) ,and I mistakenly assumed that the pattern "can do sth than sb does sth" is syntactically unacceptable.

Comment: No problem - glad I didn't misread your question :) . Nothing wrong with option C; it just makes somewhat different assumptions about the context. Since the context isn't specified, it can be a guessing game sometimes. Some people call the 'dialect' of English used in exams *Exam English* (as a parody of American English or British English etc).

Comment: If that's the test question, it's a stupid question and doesn't test anything usefully. This is often true of multiple-choice questions about English grammar and usage, since English is a multiple-choice language and there are always lots of ways to say anything grammatically, including all the choices in this question. What's the point of paying any attention to this question? There's plenty more even worse where it came from.

Comment: @John Lawler Thank you for broadening my horizon. Nothing further need to be discussed about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question is:

> Is Randy's ability to swim better than I do the consequence of his being a very good swimmer? Rather, they are, I think, two facts simply coextensive with each other, and as such should be joined by 'and' instead of 'so'.

Here's the relevant dictionary definition:

> **so** *conjunction*
>   1 And for this reason; therefore.
>   ‘it was still painful so I went to see a specialist’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/so)

Although you have a point that just because "he is a very good swimmer", it doesn't necessarily follow that he'd swim better than someone else. However, if the context allows an assumption that the speaker isn't a *very* good swimmer, the fact that "he" is (a very good swimmer) is enough to admit the (possibility of) the entailment. The use of the intensifier "very" is consistent with that assumption.

In this case, the intent seems to be to treat his ability as a justification for the conclusion. In turn, that justifies the use of *so*. Using *and* in place of *so* leaves the sentence rather bland - two facts are juxtaposed to no real effect.

You also ask:

> Is the sequence "can swim better than I can" more appropriate than "can swim better than I do"?

*Can ... can* highlights the parallel. However, in this context, "better than I do" has the sense of "better than I *can swim*" (*do* -> *can swim*). As such, *do* does work in this sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've cleared my mind of doubts with your sunccint, easy explanation.